# My all.js file is not being generated

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I deployed my latest application, my all.js file was never created. It's because of this that my entire website receives a 500 error.

I can't find too much information on the all.js file out there.

Does anyone know how this file is generated, and what may have caused this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it turns out that in my _head.haml , my javascript_include tags had an additional or innaprioriately written option.

```
= javascript_include_tag 'jquery-1.3.2.min.js', 'jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js', 'swfobject.js', 'jquery.dirtyform.js', 'jquery.Jcrop.min.js', 'application', 'http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&v=2&key=ABQIAAAAYfI_xw3MwUbmAScWsa72VBSeiHve5IwsMuqAjxrbixTJ6mqDsxTZLbNcpVxq9PneOXm7mkBjelEQpw', :cache => true
```

Simply removing the cache option at the end allowed rails' auto caching to compile this into an all.js .

For the record, that is set up in my environements/production.rb as :

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
```

Which I would imagine is a sleek way load a site faster when all the .js files and .css files are consolidated to two master files.